# R. Conversion of factor from dataframe into numeric format only works for complete column, not subset

Tags: r

I would like to use a T test for a variable (`a`) that can be separated into two different groups (`1` and `2`) by a grouping variable from column `c` (`1` and `2`) and a Shapiro test for normal distribution. First I defined the two samples for the t test:

```
a_group1 <- data[data$c == 1,"a", header = FALSE]
a_group2 <- data[data$c == 2,"a", header = FALSE]
```

Next, I performed the t test, which worked fine:

```
t.test(x = a_group1, y = a_group2, paired = FALSE, var.equal = TRUE)
```

Then I wanted to test for normal distribution using the Shapiro test, but R declared that the factors were not numeric. Therefore, I converted columns a and c into numeric by

```
data$a <- as.numeric(as.character(data$y2))
data$c <- as.numeric(as.character(data$c1))
```

Using the `class()` returns "numeric" for both subsets.

The Shapiro test works fine for the complete column `a`, and I can also use the `hist()` function without trouble.

However, if I want to test the subsets (groups 1 and 2 with the grouping variables from column c)

```
shapiro.test(a_group1)
```

I receive an error that

> is.numeric(x) is not TRUE

```
shapiro.test(as.numeric(a_group1))
```

Returns

> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

The complete column `a` seems to be "numeric", however, not the grouped subsets; and I am lost with the last error.

I'll be happy to provide any additional information!

Comment: What package do you have loaded that makes the following code run? `data[data$c == 1,"a", header = FALSE]` I get "Error in `[.data.frame`(data, data$c == 1, "a", header = FALSE) :   unused argument (header = FALSE)"

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information>. Or `dput()` your data for a minimal reproducible example.